# Regex not working with Stream filter()

Tags: java, regex, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to get certain text out from a line that I get when using the new `Stream` in Java 8.

This is what I am reading in:

```
46 [core1]
56 [core1]
45 [core1]
45 [core2]
67 [core2]
54 [core2]
```

And here is the code I read it with currently:

```
Path path = Paths.get("./src/main/resources/", "data.txt");
            try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)){
                List<Integer> temps = new ArrayList<>();
                lines
                        .filter(line -> line.contains("[core1]"))
                        .filter(line -> line.contains("(\\d+).*"))
                        .flatMapToInt(temperature -> IntStream.of(Integer.parseInt(temperature)))
                        .forEach(System.out::println);
                System.out.print(temps.size());
            }
```

I have checked the regex expression in https://www.regex101.com/ and it seems to work fine.
Also if I just search for the `[core1]` string, it will find it.

The problem is that when using all of this together, I get 0 matches.
My logic behind this currently is that I read a line, see what core it is, and then get it's number before it. After that I want to add it to a List.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Read the javadoc of contains(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29. Does it accept regexes?

Comment: Does not say anything about it. Would be logical to have the support tough. Any way to get this working in some hackish style?

Comment: I guess you are looking for `String#matches` instead of `contains`... Though you'll need to extract the integer from the line before calling `parseInt`. And calling `flatMapToInt` by creating an `IntStream` with one element is not very useful. Just use `mapToInt` instead...

Comment: @Kaspar if a javadoc says: "Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.", then no, it's not logical for it to support regexes. Methods don't do what you think they do. They do what the documentation says they do.

Comment: Not related to your question, but there is no need to flatMapToInt for a single item. Simple use mapToInt. `.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)`  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`contains` works only with strings (regexes not supported)... you can use `line.matches("(\\d+).*")` for achieving the same.

Comment: If your file is very large, you can cache the compiled regex [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for improved speed. `Pattern` is thread safe (immutable) so you can even use it in a multithreaded context if need be.

Comment: @Giovanni Botta: right, and if you have a compiled pattern, you can use [`asPredicate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#asPredicate--) to create a filter, so you can still do it in one line: `.filter(Pattern.compile("[core1]").asPredicate()) .filter(Pattern.compile("(\\d+).*").asPredicate())`